# Duties of a "Plus One"

Tags: etiquette, weddings

A long time platonic friend is going to a wedding in a few weeks and has invited me as her plus one. She is buying the wedding gift and saying it is from both of us. I'll be transporting her to and from the wedding, which is in her city (where I used to live too). I'll be coming in from *my* city, an hour away, and returning there afterwards.

**What is traditionally expected of a "plus one" for a wedding?** I don't think she is expecting anything, but perhaps she just assumes that I will do certain things, like bring flowers or a corsage. I've never been a plus one before and my knowledge of the social niceties is very limited. We are not dating and have never dated in the past.

I am in Ontario, Canada, as is my platonic friend and the wedding.

I realize that social rules are not necessarily as hard and fast as, say, rules of the road or tax legislation but I feel as if the general principles for plus ones must be known. I just don't know them. Some guidance here would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to IPS! Unfortunately, **asking "What should I do?" questions are [off topic](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1310/are-what-should-i-do-questions-on-topic-here) here.**  Your question should have a *specific goal*, for example ("How can I present myself as an excellent plus one on the wedding day?"). You may also want to put this question under the "etiquette" tag after you're done [editing](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/posts/15564/edit) your question. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, I took the liberty of rephrasing so it's more clearly not a "what should I do" (e.g. "make a choice for me") style question. If I've misrepresented your question, please feel free to roll back or [edit] again!

Comment: "social niceties" are cultural dependent. Please add at least a country, and probably any identifiable sub-culture within it.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Is @Henry the same as user18820?  If so, the accounts should probably be merged (Contact Stack Exchange for help with that).  If not, then the edit seems to change the question.